# How do I open app settings in Nativescript iOS?

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to open the app settings on iOS devices.
I do not know how to properly translate the open url snippet to javascript.

I tried three approaches and none of them work:

```
application.ios.nativeApp.shared.open(URL(UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString), nil);
application.ios.nativeApp.sharedApplication.openURL(NSURL.URLWithString(UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString));
application.ios.nativeApp.shared.openURL(NSURL.URLWithString(UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.openURL(NSURL.URLWithString(UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString));
```

Use [tns-platform-declarations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations) if you are using TypeScript for IntelliSense support with device apis.